# Best way to handle a form post in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, forms

I'm doing a plugin that needs to be able to post data to a third party API. Users will fill out a form and press submit.

The form itself - would it be "correct" to simply append html to a page content with a the_content() filter? I'm adding the form based on a bunch of settings saves as meta for each page or post. I'd like to avoid tampering with templates...

With other words; if some meta is set for the page - append some html (the form that users will input data to).

Also - when users press "submit" in that form - how should I handle the request? Right now I'm thinking that I will load wordpress in a totally separate php-file (in order to get my hand on all those funky wp-functions and constants) - but that feels kind of wrong...

Is there a build-in way to both display the form and then handle the request?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Nothing really - asking to know what the best practice is - before I do anything wrong.

Comment: It strikes me that I could probably post the form to the same page and in my plugin look for any POST data - and handle it that way.

However - what if I want to send the form using jQuery? Is there any way to tell WP not to print anything / stop all output to screen - from within my plugin?

Comment: Best practice on [wordpress.se] is to show your research effort and possibly some code that isn't working. I'm certain you'll find enough information on here to get started and come back with the above mentioned.

Comment: Maybe you could point me in the right direction for best practice? Or perhaps - if you don't have an answer - not reply at all?

I have been looking for an answer - without finding anything that suits my needs. I think an answer here might help some other developers in the future. But ok, I can give you some code... although - as I said - I'm not asking for precise code - but rather a hint on what path to go...

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I finally found a way to do this - and I believe it can be seen as a best practice...

I wanted to post with jQuery from a form on the WP front end. Was a lot easier than I expected.

First of all, make sure you have javascript to capture the form event (when a user presses the submit button). Post the form to the wordpress file admin-ajax.php - found using:

```
admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
```

And - this is important - make sure you add a parameter called "action" in the post request. The value of "action" will be used to name the wp-function you will use as callback (or form handler).

Let's say you give the action parameter a value of "my_callback". You would then create the two actions:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_callback', 'my_callback_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_callback', 'my_callback_function' );
```

Then - simply create the function my_callback_function() - and you are free to use any $_POST data in it.

What you echo out in that function will be returned to the initial jQuery request